# Error using offset to calculate previous row in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, offset

I need to generate a column containing the previous value of the date column partition by group. This is an example of the table

```
Group   Date
A   01/02/2022
A   15/07/2022
A   28/11/2022
B   05/09/2022
B   06/10/2022
B   29/11/2022
B   19/12/2022
C   05/08/2022
C   15/12/2022
C   22/01/2023
```

To reach that I have created the new column using this DAX formula:

```
Previous Date = 
var groups = 'Sample'[Group]
var dates = 'Sample'[Date]
REturn
CALCULATE(
        MAX('Sample'[Date]),
        FILTER(
            'Sample',
            'Sample'[Date] < dates &&
            'Sample'[Group] = groups
        )     
)
```

This is working fine. However the idea is to use the OFFSET formula. But I'm not so sure why I'm getting always a circular dependency error:

```
OFfset Previous = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Sample'[Date]),
    OFFSET(
        -1,
        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED('Sample'), 'Sample'[Date], 'Sample'[Group])
        ))
```

Or with this one

[image]

What am I missing in this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.

[image]

```
Offset Previous = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Sample'[Date]),
    OFFSET(
        -1,
        ORDERBY('Sample'[Date]),
        PARTITIONBY([Group])
    ), 
    REMOVEFILTERS()
)
```

Regarding your circular dependency, it is due to not taking the other calculated column out of the filter context. Calculated column 1 depends on calculated column 2 and vice versa hence the circular dependency. You  can read more here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/

Comment: Hi David Bacci. Thanks a lof for your help. The metric is working fine. However, I'm still a little bit confused. I have deleted the "Previous Date" column from the model. If I try to implement you DAX code without the REMOVEFILTERS() option I'm still getting the circular dependency error. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Do you have any other calculated columns in your table? Are you able to share a .pbix with the problem?

Comment: Your sample data works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes. It is strange. Y only have the Sample table with the 2 regular columns and the one I'm trying to create with your formula (without the REMOVEFILTERS()). I've updated the original post with the error.

Comment: You need the REMOVEFILTERS() to escape the circular dependency. Read the link I sent for a full explanation.